# Vuejs single file component (.vue) model update inside the <script> tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs and I'm trying to build a simple single file component for testing purpose.

This component simply displays a bool and a button that change the bool value.
It also listen for a "customEvent" that also changes the bool value

```
<template>
  {{ mybool }}
  <button v-on:click="test">test</button>
</template>

<script>    
  ipcRenderer.on('customEvent', () => {
    console.log('event received');
    this.mybool = !this.mybool;
  });


  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mybool: true,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      test: () => {
        console.log(mybool);
        mybool = !mybool;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

The button works fine. when I click on it the value changes.
but when I receive my event, the 'event received' is displayed in the console but my bool doesn't change.

Is there a way to access the components data from my code?

Thanks and regards,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `ipcRenderer.on(...)` into vuejs's lifecycle hooks like `created`.
See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Thanks! moved it to beforeMount() {...} worked like a charm!

Comment: @Eric Very glad it helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up the event listener outside of the component's options which you export by using

```
export default{ //... options }
```

Set up the event listener inside the vue options so the vue instance has control over it, in your case modifying dara property

As **choasia** suggested move the event listener to `created() life cycle hook:

```
<template>
  {{ mybool }}
  <button v-on:click="test">test</button>
</template>

<script>    



  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mybool: true,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      test: () => {
        console.log(mybool);
        mybool = !mybool;
      },
    },
    created(){
        ipcRenderer.on('customEvent', () => {
            console.log('event received');
            this.mybool = !this.mybool;
        });
    }
  };
</script>
```

Now you component will starting listening for that particular even when the component is created